# How to get rid if date and time from MobaXterm?

Tags: terminal, mobaxterm

I just installed MobaXterm on my new work computer and I just couldn't figure out how to get rid of the date and time in the terminal. Can someone please help me out?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Pb0w.png)

Answer (score 8):

Never mind. I just figured out that **MobaFont** is the culprit. To get rid of the date and time from the MobaXterm terminal, all you have to do is to change the Font style from **MobaFont** to anything else. Cheers :)

Answer (score 1):

Here are the steps based on what the OP mentioned in his answer,

It's in menu "Settings" --> "Configuration" --> 2nd tab ("Terminal") --> click  the button "Default terminal font settings"